# Questions about Randomized Median algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, randomized

In textbook by Mitzenmacher and Upfal [here](http://mcs.ninhthuan.top/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Probability-and-Computing-2nd-Edition.pdf), they write in page 62, the following:

> By repeating Algorithm 3.1 until it succeeds in finding the median, we can obtain an iterative algorithm that never fails but has a random running time.

Note that that the algorithm has linear running time. Now, if we repeat this algorithm for k times, then the running time would be O(kn). Now, how they say that "By repeating algorithm until it succeeds in finding the median, we can obtain an iterative algorithm"?
I do not understand how they get an iterative algorithm. In order to get an iterative algorithm, then the algorithm must call itself and must have a logarithmic running time.

Another question: What does they mean by "it has a random running time"?

About iterated algorithm, please look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm).
To see the algorithm, look at the book in page 59.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with your second question. A *random running time* is a running time which is a random variables. As a simple example, consider an algorithm which tosses a fair coin until it come up heads. The running time is a random variable whose distribution is, roughly speaking, geometric. This is not so different from the randomized median algorithm: every run of the median algorithm is like a coin toss, and you iterate running it until it comes up "heads" (succeeds).

Now, for the name *iterative algorithm*. Here is the algorithm you describe:

```
repeat
  run Algorithm 3.1
until the algorithm succeeds
```

This is the epitome of iteration – the algorithm consists of a single loop.

You write

> In order to get an iterative algorithm, then the algorithm must call itself and must have a logarithmic running time.

I'm not really sure why you think that an iterative algorithm should call itself. Indeed, algorithms calling themselves are usually known as *recursive algorithms*. (As an aside, an iteration of the form considered here is a special case of recursion known as [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).)

Also, I'm not really sure why the algorithm should have a logarithmic running time. The standard algorithm for summing an array is iterative and runs in linear time.

Comment: I suspect that some information is missing here – next time, try to include all relevant information in the post. Don't forget that we can't read your mind.

Comment: I'm really, really sorry about this confusion. I said about "iterative algorithm" must call itself and must have a logarithmic running time; because I read this page: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) and I read the title mistakenly as "iterated algorithm" instead of "iterated logarithm". So, I thought that "iterative algorithm" must has a logarithmic running time. I'm really sorry about this silly and very silly question. Huge Thanks Prof. Yuval to clarify my mistakes. Now, everything is very, very clear.